# How to generate multiple print statement in R script

Tags: r

```
roll2 <- function(defaultDie = 1:6)
{

    dice <- sample(defaultDie,size=2,replace = T)
##output for dice is not printed    
dice
   sprintf("Sum is %d ", sum(dice))

    ##sum(dice)
}
```

Expected Output
[1] 5 6
[1] 11
Right now im getting just
[1] 11
I want to understand why dice statement is ignored while running the script

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify it, it's not clear what you want to do with this code. But if all you want is to print `dice` inside `roll2`, you have to use `print(dice)` explicitly.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much Molx, I apologize for being unclear. My objective was to print the out put of dice vector and also sum of the same. Print statement works fine in this case. However, if you could please explain why when we write just dice the out put is not printed?  why does the code goes to sprintf statement directly?

Comment: You need to explicitly tell the program to `print` something to the console. Computers are stupid unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As @Moix and @chappers commented you have to explicitly print everything you want to see. There are four options:

```
print(dice)

show(dice)

cat(dice, "\n")

write(dice, file = stdout())
```